# Types of OCaml functions

Tags: ocaml

I started learning functional programming (OCaml), but I don't understand one important topic about functional programming: types.

Can anyone explain me this solution please?

Have a test this week and can't get reach the resolution..

```
let f a b c = a (a b c) 0;;
f: ('a -> int -> 'a) -> 'a -> int -> 'a
```

Comment: You seem to be asking about the *type* of this function, but unfortunately I don't see a question to be answered. When you enter an expression, the OCaml toplevel tells you its type. That's what's happening here. Types are explained in [Chapter 6.4 of the OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/types.html). But a tutorial might be a better place to start (I couldn't find one in the time I have, sorry).

Comment: Yes.. the type of function is what i cant determine but thanks!

Comment: A tutorial that Jeffrey could have pointed out had he had the time is http://www.mauny.net/data/papers/mauny-1995b.pdf

Answer (score 4):

```
let f a b c = a (a b c) 0;;
```

Your confusion involves types and type inference, i.e., when you define a function or binding, you don't need to give explicit types for its parameters, nor the function/binding itself, OCaml will figure it out if your definition of function/binding is correct.

So, let's do some manual inferences ourselves. If a human can do, then the compiler can also do.

---

**1.**

```
let x = 1
```

`1` is integer, so x must be an integer. So you don't need to do `int x = 1` as in other languages, right?

**2.**

```
let f x = 1
```

If there are multiple variable names between `let` and `=`, then it must be a function definition, right? Otherwise, it won't make sense. In Java like language, it also makes no sense to say `int x y = 1`, right?

So `f` is a function and x is must be a parameter. Since the righthand side of `=` is an integer, then we know `f` will return an integer. For x, we don't know, so `x` will be thought as a polymorphic type `'a`.

So `f: 'a -> int = <fun>`.

**3.**

```
let f a b c = a (a b c) 0;;
```

- `f` is a function, with parameters `a`, `b`, `c`.
- `a` must be a function, because on the righthand side of `=`, it is a function application.
- `a` takes two arguments: `(a b c)` and 0. `0` is an integer, so the 2nd parameter of `a` must be an integer type.
- Look inside `(a b c)`, `c` is the 2nd arguement, so `c` must be integer.
- We can't infer on `b`. So `b` is `'a`.
- Since `(a b c)` can be the 1st argument of `a`, and `(a b c)` itself is an application on function `a`, the return type of `a` will have the same type of `b` which is `'a`.

Combine information above together, you get `f: ('a -> int -> 'a) -> 'a -> int -> 'a`.

---

If you want to learn it formally, https://realworldocaml.org/ is your friend.